# Disable Google Glass Auto Upgrade

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

There has been a few issues caused by recent Glass upgrade to XE19.1.

My application suffers the [same issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=578&q=MediaRecorder&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary).

There seems to be other bugs caused by the same upgrade
[EyeGestures NOT working in 19.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876059/eyegestures-not-working-in-19-1)

Is there a way we can disable the auto upgrade by google? 
My application will be used within firewall, any possibility to block certain IP or Port?

Any other recommendation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Developer website (http://developers.google.com/glass) and navigate to Tools & Downloads / System and Kernel downloads (https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/system).

Follow the instructions to install a rooted boot loader for a specific version. Once you have rooted you will no longer receive automatic updates.  The downside is that you will have violated your warrantee.

Comment: Once the device is rooted. Is there a way to unroot so we can get back the warranty?

Comment: Theoretically you can just re-install the "factory" boot image provided on the Google site.  I'm not sure if that will re-activate the warrantee.  It is possible that Google is tracking everything behind the scenes and as soon as your device shows up as rooted some kind of flag shows up on your account.

Comment: Winston Liu, try re-locking the OEM via the command line in order to get back your warranty. I had watched a video on rooting a Samsung Nexus 7, and the person who had posted the video had indicated that he was able to regain his warranty by simply re-locking his OEM.